# Is using Object.wait and Object.notify directly a code smell?

Tags: java, concurrency

This might be controversial, but I just realized I very seldom use wait and notify directly. Instead, I use some higher-level construct from the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. Are there use cases where wait and notify are the only solution or should they only be used when building higher-level constructs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there use cases where wait and notify are the only solution or should they only be used when building higher-level constructs?

They should only be used when building higher-level constructs.  If you have a case where the existing higher-level constructs don't solve your problem, you don't want to revert to wait/notify; you want to design a higher-level construct that solves your problem.  You may implement it with wait/notify.

For example, I once had a problem that required concurrent execution of a collection of tasks with hierarchical dependencies, where the dependency conditions involved a combination of conjunction ("and") and disjunction ("or").  I.e., there were cases where one task's condition was "Task A is done and Task B is done," cases where it was "Task A is done or Task B is done," and various combinations of these (e.g., "Task A is done, and either Task B or Task C is done").

So I wrote a small utility library that provided an interface for clients to submit collections of tasks annotated with their conditions, submitted these tasks to an `Executor` as soon as their preconditions were met, and monitored task completion to kick off newly eligible tasks.  Some of that was implemented using `java.util.concurrent` (mainly `Executor` and `Semaphore`), but other parts involved using wait/notify (the "coordinator" thread is notified of task completion with wait/notify).

So the code ended up much easier to understand and troubleshoot, and later we found other uses for the same task coordinator library.

Answer (score 3):

From my POV, you are absolutely right : it's far better to use higher-order constructs like the ones from java.util.concurrent. The wait/notify system is error-prone, low-level, and has issues (like missed signals - the "notifier" emits the signal before the "waiter" calls wait()).

So, I cannot see any case where using wait/notify would be better. Except if you're stuck with Java pre-1.5 of course.

Comment: saying that there is _no_ case where they would be better is a bit narrow-minded.  the higher level constructs in the concurrent package certainly cover most common concurrency scenarios, but they are by no means exhaustive

Comment: @jtahlborn can you think of an example off of the top of your head? I'm curious if there's a particular class of problem that they're suited to.

Comment: Well, there is nothing you can do with wait/notify that you cannot do with Condition.await/signal in java.util.concurrent. So technically, wait/notify really looks deprecated in any java 1.5+ project

Comment: okay, but for standard usage there's no difference between using await/signal and wait/notify, and using a synchronized() block is simpler than using lock() w/ a try/finally block, so i'd prefer wait/notify for the simple case.  (obviously there are other, additional things you can do w/ Condition, but assuming that's not necessary).

Comment: @scompt.com - sure, anytime you need to manage shared state in a multi-threaded system.  an example from my current codebase is a class similar to a threadpool, except using separate processes instead of threads (so i need to keep track of how many procs are currently running and handle launching/queueing new work as appropriate).  there's nothing in the concurrent package to do this for me.

Comment: Multi-*process* ? You manage many JVMs in parallel ? If so, how can wait/notify even be of any use ?

Comment: @OlivierCroisier - yes, i have a controller managing multiple processes.  the _controller_ needs to manage its internal state (how many processes are currently running, how many are waiting to be started, etc.).