# wake up waiting threads

Tags: java, multithreading

this class works with an executor. the thing is that at some point i want to shut it down, but even if i'm changing the terminateRequested to "true" it wont help those threads stuck waiting in "takeTask" because the vector tasks at that point is always empty.
i need them somehow to get to "e.shutDown()" line in run()

```
public class RunnableStudent implements Runnable{

public void run() {

    while(!terminateRequested){

        this.takeTask();
        this.giveSolution();

    }


    e.shutdown();

}


private synchronized void takeTask(){


          while(tasks.isEmpty()){
               try {

                 this.wait();
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }

         DoSomeWork();
}

public synchronized void shutDown(){


    terminateRequested = true;
    this.notifyAll();

}
```

Comment: can I see how the terminateRequested is defined ?

Comment: terminateRequested is a boolean. i have 3 instances of RunnableStudent and after i'm done i just call s.shutDown() on each of them

Comment: have you checked if terminateRequested is volatile?

Comment: I believe that java provides `interrupted` flag. That is why you need to invent the `terminateRequested` yourself?

Comment: i don't want anything to be interrupted. i just want to give a shut down request by myself when i'm done. that's what i need terminateRequested for.

Comment: Why don't you want to develop your own language, to create the threads and terminate them? It must be simpler than using existing mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you are having three different RunnableStudent instance ( each instance per thread) and assumed the tasks and terminateRequested are local variables , you dont need to syncronized .becuase there is nothing you are sharing between threads. 
 
Second , if you are using executors , you can use thread pool , that case you dont need to do wait and notify yourself , once the work is completed all the threads ( n number of threads configured while pool iniitalize) in pool will wait for next request ( through executors.submit/execute) . And you can use shutdown / shutdownNow at any given point based on your condition. 
 
Finaly to answer your question, just change the **while loop to if conditon in taketask().** All your problems will resolve . because your waiting logic will still holds good with main while loop in run method.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to break out of your `while tasks.isEmpty()){` loop and out of your `while(!terminateRequested){` loop

so I suggest that when you do

```
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

you change it to

```
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
     terminateRequested = true;
     return;
}
```

As I can not see your `giveSolution` method I can not tell you have to change it.

Alternatively you could through the `InterruptedException` from the `takeTask` method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using executor service you can call it's [shutdownNow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29) method that is going to actively shut down threads without waiting.

Combining Object.wait and Object.notify with java.util.concurrent smells as per [Is using Object.wait and Object.notify directly a code smell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494086/is-using-object-wait-and-object-notify-directly-a-code-smell)

Answer (score 0):

You need break the loop of while(tasks.isEmpty())
so change the code like this:

```
public class RunnableStudent implements Runnable{

 private Thread thread;
 public void run() {

    thread = Thread.currentThread();
    while(!terminateRequested){

        this.takeTask();
        this.giveSolution();

   }


   e.shutdown();

 }

 private synchronized void takeTask(){


      while(tasks.isEmpty()){
           try {

             this.wait();
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             break;
          }
      }

     DoSomeWork();
}

public synchronized void shutDown(){

     terminateRequested = true;
     thread.interupt();

}
```